# REGEX to get all numbers in a string, even if other characters are in between

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet populated with information from a real estate website. 
The phone numbers came across in a single cell like this `*Cell #* (602) 695-2036` or `*Cell #* 602-575-1008`. I had an `REGEXEXTRACT()` function using `\d-\d-\d` which worked for numbers formatted like the second, but I need something that works on all cell number strings, regardless of formatting or characters between. So I want `(602) 695-2036` to return `6026952036` and `602-575-1008` to return `6025751008`.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/104IPz26XGpBUwxP82WaL-f3oYozrDwZV8A1yGlg7gvk/edit#gid=0). Numbers are in row 5 and one is in row 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace all non-digits with nothing. Something like

```
=regexreplace(A1, "\D+", )
```

should work. You can also iterate the regexreplace over an array..

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A1:A), regexreplace(A1:A, "\D+",),))
```

Change range to suit and see if that works?

Comment: Both of these work, though the first works a bit better for the needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your sample sheet for A5:

```
=REGEXreplace(A5,"\D+", "")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can match all numbers with the regular expression `\d`. Then just append your list of matches together.

Here is an example of this in JavaScript:

```js
// INIT
var text = '(602) 695-2036';
var result = '';

// PRINT START
console.log("START: "+text);

// GET MATCHES
var matches = text.match(/\d/g);

// LOOP MATCHES
for(var index = 0; index < matches.length; index++){
 
 // APPEND TO RESULT
 result += matches[index];

}

// PRINT RESULT
console.log("RESULT: "+result);
```

Comment: That looks great for something where I can loop through regex results, but I don't know of any way to do so with =REGEXEXTRACT() on Google Sheets. I need this done in a single cell, rather than a javascript function.